# WSO2 ESB Web Services Proxy for Axis1

Tags: wso2, axis, esb

For some legacy Web Services using AXIS1 (such as AXIS 1.4) as an endpoint, is there any tutorial or examples for WSO2 ESB to communicate with AXIS1 WSDL, and act as a service proxy for the client using REST or AXIS2?
I am currently using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1, but cannot find any reference to help resolve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK there is no any guide, But if you point a webservice hosted in Axis1, do you see any issue at ESB end when send/receive requests/response.?

Comment: The problem here is Axis1 is rpc/encoded based and the structure is totally different from Axis2 (doc/literal, which is adopted by WSO2 ESB framework). So for the Web Services site using Axis1 SOAP, WSO2 ESB cannot communicate with that site. 
Here is an example: https://primavera-unifier.oracleindustry.com/ws/services/mainservice?wsdl. This site uses Axis1.4. When WSO2 ESB trying to create a proxy service for that site, it will shows " Error trying to add the proxy service to the ESB configuration : <Proxy Name> :: Unknown WSDL format.. not WSDL 1.1 or WSDL 2.0" error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create service for specified service without problem in WSO ESB2 4.8.1, at least I've did not get any errors about WSDL format.

But, you are totally right - there are some issues then you are trying to use Axis1 based service in Axis2 based WSO2 ESB:

1. As you correctly mentioned, Axis1 used rpc/encoded style, and Axis2 based on document style. To make it working together, then you publishing wsdl for service, you should use followed property, to publish service in WSO2 also in rpc format:
   `<parameter name="useOriginalwsdl">true</parameter>`
2. Even if you will try to use service with followed definition:

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
          name="PrimaveraProxy"
          transports="https,http"
          statistics="disable"
          trace="disable"
          startOnLoad="true">
      <target>
         <outSequence>
            <send/>
         </outSequence>
         <endpoint>
            <wsdl service="MainService2Service"
                  port="mainservice"
                  uri="https://primavera-unifier.oracleindustry.com/ws/services/mainservice?wsdl"/>
         </endpoint>
      </target>
      <publishWSDL uri="https://primavera-unifier.oracleindustry.com/ws/services/mainservice?wsdl"/>
      <parameter name="useOriginalwsdl">true</parameter>
      <description/>
   </proxy>`

You will get error like (then you will try to call some of the methods):

> The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is
>   /services/PrimaveraProxy.PrimaveraProxyHttpSoap12Endpoint and the WSA
>   Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact
>   the server administrator.

It is because original WSDL has empty soapAction parameters, for example:

```
<wsdl:operation name="getRoleList">
<wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
```

To fix it, you should edit original WSDL locally, by inserting names for soapActions, and then place it into service definition (for example inline, or via registry).

Hope these advices will help you